# paintComponent calling a variable

Tags: java, swing, variables, paintcomponent

Here is the situation. I have this code. When you remove the variable a in the second class. Program is working. It just draw a line. But I want to put a variable is "a". Then in first class I want to declare it. Then I want to use it. How can I do that.

Basically Where can I put the variable a in the first class(Grafik3) to work in second class in NewLabel method ?

```
public class Grafik3 extends  JFrame{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Grafik3()

    {        add(new YeniLabel("Paint component.............. "));          }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Grafik3 cer = new Grafik3();

        cer.setTitle("Paint component");
        cer.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // çerçevenin merkezi
        cer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        cer.setSize(300,120);
        cer.setVisible(true);

    }

}


class YeniLabel extends JLabel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public YeniLabel(String s){super(s); }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g,int a){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(a, 0, 70, 70);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do that, you are not *overriding* the function anymore. You are creating an *overload*. This is not what you want. Instead try to make the `int a` a class member and set the variable to the appropriate value before you render the component.

The reason why it doesn't work is exactly because you created an overload for that method. Which means that this method is not used when rendering. Instead the original `paintComponent(Graphics)` method is used. The call used for rendering is *always* `paintComponent(Graphics)`. So if you create a method next to the original one with the same name but different parameters (which is called *an overload*), this method does not replace the original one, but is just a new one and they exists both at the same time.

Comment: Actually I ask for that to use a variable that I dont know the value.

Comment: For example the value of variable will be came from the outside or a user. That is why I ask such a question. Do you have any link to help me?

Comment: Well, make the variable a class member and make a setter for it.

Comment: Google that. It's a method that changes the value of a classmember.

Answer (score 0):

Call a getter function.

In your main class:

```
YeniLabel yeni = new YeniLabel("Paint component.............. ");
add(yeni);

//whenever you want to get it:
int a = yeni.getA();
```

And in your YenniLabel class:

```
class YeniLabel extends JLabel {


    int a = 25;

    public YeniLabel(String s){super(s); }

    public void getA(){
       return a;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(a, 0, 70, 70);

    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the variable "a" in the Grafik3 class ? How can I do that?

Comment: I understand a little bit but I need specific information which part will go where ?

Comment: YeniLabel yeni = new YeniLabel("Paint component.............. ");
add(yeni);   I put them in the Grafik3 method. and I remove the int a=25 in the second class

Comment: Right, the first part goes in your Grafik3 class (the main class). You need a variable named 'a' at the top-level of your YeniLabel class though, so you shouldn't just take it out.